# Did prophet sulayman understand "machine level language"

Tags: tafseer, hadith-interpretation, prophets

There are reports where a wolf spoke and a bull spoke to humans. Face value it appears they spoke to humans in the human language and can be interpreted as "high level langauage"[1]

Quran speaks about prophet suleyman understanding the speech of ants.***can this be construed as native speech or "machine level language"***? [2]

---

[1]

> Sahih al-Bukhari 3471
> Narrated Abu Huraira:
> Once Allah's Messenger (ﷺ); offered the morning prayer and then faced the people and said, "While a man was driving a cow, he suddenly rode over it and beat it. The cow said, "We have not been created for this, but we have been created for sloughing." On that the people said astonishingly, "Glorified be Allah! A cow speaks!" The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "I believe this, and Abu Bakr and `Umar too, believe it, although neither of them was present there. While a person was amongst his sheep, a wolf attacked and took one of the sheep. The man chased the wolf till he saved it from the wolf, where upon the wolf said, 'You have saved it from me; but who will guard it on the day of the wild beasts when there will be no shepherd to guard them except me (because of riots and afflictions)? ' " The people said surprisingly, "Glorified be Allah! A wolf speaks!" The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "But I believe this, and Abu Bakr and` Umar too, believe this, although neither of them was present there."

[2] O you ants, enter your dwellings so that Sulayman and his hosts would not definitely crush you, Quran 27:18

Suitable edits be done to improve the question please.